# Flutter Get.width or initialize MediaQuery.of(context).size not working in Release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

When ı use get.width or height at first page in project or initialize like this ;

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

also SizeConfig page :

```
class SizeConfig {
  static late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static late double width;
  static late double height;
  static late double blockSizeHorizontal;
  static late double blockSizeVertical;
  static late double res;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    width = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    height = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
  }
```

}

It is not working.

But when ı use debug mode they are working well. Yes the release mode faster than debug mode but how can we solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
void init(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  // executes after build
_mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    width = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    height = _mediaQueryData.size.height;

});
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, ı used that in didChangeDependencies method. But why Get.width doesn't work :/

Comment: Could you please add log to didChangeDependencies() method?

Comment: I noticed that when we use bottombar your method is not working, if we root a page then it works.

Comment: If you will check that sometime didChangeDependencies() isn't getting called. So i think this is the route cause. If you will put the log on init method and didChangeDependencies() method of same widget then you will able to identify. Also please add log to build method as well.